# Setting up WordPress on Suse Enterprise Server

Tags: wordpress, apache, azure, nginx, suse

I'm trying to set up WordPress on Suse server 12.

- I have successfully setup Apache, PHP and MySQL.
- I have created the MariaDB database and setup the user account with all passwords, etc.
- I have Downloaded the latest WordPress and extracted it.
- I have moved all directories around as instructed.

But i cannot access the last setup process via the ip address (from another desktop)

---

WebPage with Error Message:

---

Access forbidden!

You don't have permission to access the requested directory. There is either no index document or the directory is read-protected.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

Error 403

< my ip address >
Apache/2.4.10 (Linux/SUSE)

---

Perhaps someone has successfully managed to set this up?

Note: Suse us running on a VM on Azure, accessing it through Putty.

Comment: Wait...why did you install MySQL and then set up MariaDB?

Comment: ignore the MySQL part mentioned in the first bullet. 

I set up the dbs with MariaDB

Comment: What if you create a index.html with same sample content, and try open the url again.

Comment: Should really go on Server Fault as this isn't a programming question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this from the attached tutorial:

> Out of the box, Apache will be accessible from the local machine. If you want to allow other machines to access the web server, you'll need to do the following:

- Open the file /etc/sysconfig/SuSEfirewall2 with your favorite text
  editor.
- Add the line FW_CONFIGURATIONS_EXT="apache2"
- Save and close the file.
- Restart the firewall with the command sudo systemctl restart
  SuSEfirewall2

**http://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-install-a-lamp-server-on-opensuse/**

Depending on your version, it may not be exactly these steps, but somewhere along these lines.